# Function $f$ with finite preimage for a point and with $[f(x),f(y)] \subseteq \text{Im}(f)$ for $f(x) \leq f(y)$ must be continous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is quite simple. Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the following properties. If for every $c \in \text{Im}(f)$ it holds that $\{s \in (a,b):f(s)=c\}$ is finite and for $x,y \in (a,b)$ with $f(y) \geq f(x)$ it holds that $[f(x),f(y)] \subseteq \text{Im}(f)$. Then how can I show that the function must be continuous. I tried by absurd supposing it to be discontinuous, but I can't extinguish all possibilities greater than a given $\varepsilon$ simply with the finite property of the preimage of a point.

The question also ask how to give a counterexample in the case which the finite condition for the preimage of a point is removed. I think that:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0\end{cases}$$

Is a possible counterexample in $[-\pi,\pi]$, is this idea correct? The condition seemed to me to remove this type of discontinuity. But seeing this I have no idea to the finite preimage proof.

**EDIT**: The question was given by my professor, but it seems that a counter-example has been found. Probably the hypothesis is not strong enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the claim true? Maybe I am misreading the question, but

$f:[-1,1]\to [0,1):x\mapsto \begin{cases}
x+1\quad x\in [-1,0)\\ 
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x\quad x\in [0,1]
\end{cases}$

satisfies the hypotheses but is not continuous at $x=0.$